# how to get value into textbox without button click

Tags: javascript, html

am using as follows

```
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo empty($this->session->store['actual_info']['actual_total_marketing_budget']) ? '' : $this->session->store['actual_info']['actual_total_marketing_budget']; ?>"  readonly name="actual_total_marketing_budget" readonly id="actual_total_marketing_budget"  size="30" style="height:20px; " onFocus="total_marketing_budget()"/></td>
```

here the issue when clicking on the textbox only it is getting or changing value i need the value without clicking on text box what i have to do. someone help me please

Comment: Please post the actual HTML, not the PHP code. Also you could create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: please post ur js function total_marketing_budget() and also specify when you need the value?

Comment: Are you looking for how to get the new value when the value was changed. Is it??

Comment: yes am using the following function function total_marketing_budget()
   {
    var a = document.getElementById("actual_total_advertising").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("actual_total_sales_promo").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("actual_total_coop_mark").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("actual_total_press_pub_relations").value;
    
    var t = parseFloat('0'+a)+ parseFloat('0'+b)+ parseFloat('0'+c)+ parseFloat('0'+d);
    document.getElementById("actual_total_marketing_budget").value = t;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
document.getElementById('actual_total_marketing_budget').value
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thr1/ENzHL/) in action.
However, a similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563667/2476843).

Answer (score 0):

You have written the function to get the value of textbox, in `onFocus` event.

Change it to on document load like

```
<script>    
(function() {
        var textBox = document.getElementById('actual_total_marketing_budget').value
    })();
</script>
```

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wVMKN/)

Comment: excuse me it is getting value from this function function total_marketing_budget()
   {
    var a = document.getElementById("actual_total_advertising").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("actual_total_sales_promo").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("actual_total_coop_mark").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("actual_total_press_pub_relations").value;
    
    var t = parseFloat('0'+a)+ parseFloat('0'+b)+ parseFloat('0'+c)+ parseFloat('0'+d);
    document.getElementById("actual_total_marketing_budget").value = t;
   }

Comment: @user2739848 Have you checked my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wVMKN/?  you will get some idea.  otherwise create a fiddle and share it here.

Comment: excuse me can we readonly textboxes for onChange. Whether it will work or not

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this;

```
<input type ="text" value="...." id ="actual_total_marketing_budget">


<script type="text/javascript">
function actual_total_marketing_budget(){
var textbox = document.getElementById('actual_total_marketing_budget');

//the function body is the same as you have defined sue the textbox object to set the value
}

actual_total_marketing_budget();
</script>
```

Here notice that I have called the function `actual_total_marketing_budget()` after defining it that changes the value of the textbox once the page has loaded.